# How do I sidestep TT_NUMBER from StreamTokenizer

Tags: java, parsing

I replaced a call to String.split() with a loop using StreamTokenizer, because my users needed quoting functionality.  But now I'm having problems from numbers being converted to numbers instead of left as Strings.  In my loop if I get a TT_NUMBER, I convert it back to a String with Double.toString().  But that is not working for some long serial numbers that have to get sent to me; they are being converted to exponential notation.

I can change the way I am converting numbers back into Strings, but I would really like to just not parse numbers in the first place.  I see that StreamTokenizer has a parseNumbers() method, that turns on number parsing, but there doesn't seem to be a way to turn it off.  What do I have to do to create and configure a parser that is identical to the default but does not parse numbers?

Answer (score 4):

You could reset the token definitions from the `StreamTokenizer` by invoking `resetSyntax()` and then redefining the word chars to include digits as well.

The following:

```
Reader r = new BufferedReader(new StringReader("123 foo \"string \\\" literal\" 0.5"));

StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(r);

st.resetSyntax();
st.wordChars(0x23, 0xFF);
st.whitespaceChars(0x00, 0x20);
st.quoteChar('"');

while(st.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
  System.out.println(st.sval);
}
```

would print:

```
123
foo
string " literal
0.5
```